# SQL Script: Updating a column with another table pivoting on an ID

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-scripts

I have two SQL Server tables: `ORDERS` and `DELIVERIES`.

I would like to update the `ORDERS` table with a value from `DELIVERIES`. The `ORDERS` PK (`OrderID`) is common to both tables. Also, I would like to restrict the action to a specific `CustomerID` (within `ORDERS`).

`ORDERS` table:

```
OrderID | AccountID | AnalysisField1
```

`DELIVERIES` table:

```
DeliveryID | OrderID | AddressName
```

I want to update `ORDERS.AnalysisField1` with the value from `DELIVERIES.AddressName` (linked by `OrderID`) but only where `ORDERS.AccountID = '12345'`

Please help. JM

Answer (score 0):

Then try to use something like this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Orders
SET AnalysisField1 = d.Addressname
FROM dbo.Deliveries d
WHERE
    d.OrderID = dbo.Orders.OrderID
    AND dbo.Orders.AccountID = '12345'
```

If your `AccountID` column is of a **numerical** type (which the `ID` suffix would suggest), then you should *not* put unnecessary single quotes around the value in the `WHERE` clause:

```
    AND dbo.Orders.AccountID = 12345
```